# openpyxl - handling empty cells beyond "value is not None"

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm reading large Excel files into a case classes, b/w 6-12 fields in each class, is there a better way of handling empty cells in openpyxl than:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

from datetime import date
wb = load_workbook('report.xlsx')
ws = wb['data']
for row in ws.iter_rows():
        id1= row[0].value if row[0].value is not None else 0
        id2 = row[1].value if row[1].value is not None else 0.0
    id3 = row[2].value if row[2].value is not None else ""
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a function, e.g. `id1 = setdefault(....value, 0)`. The function have to return the cell `value` or `0` if empty.

Comment: What's do you think is wrong with checking and then assigning a default?

Comment: Didn't say there was anything wrong, just asked if there was 'a better way'